# robots.txt pattern matching not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, robots.txt

I need to get a pattern matching rule to get this results.

```
allow /dir/path_name.htm/something
disallow /dir/path_name/something
and disallow /dir/path_name.htm
```

Actually those two disallows are typos accumulated all along. Those pages never exist. How to stop google crawling them never again?

I tested here: http://www.frobee.com/robots-txt-check/ with the following, but seems nothing working.

```
Allow: /dir/*.htm/?*
Disallow: /dir/*
```

What went wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the spec:

http://www.robotstxt.org/norobots-rfc.txt

Wildcards (`*`) are not allowed. The paths are just exact matches. My guess is that you're using some form of rewriting and you don't want multiple ulrs with the same content to show up. In that case this may be a better solution:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Comment: Actually wildcards aren't really needed there either, because `Disallow: /path/to/dir/` means ignore the whole folder with contents, nit just this specific uri...

Comment: If you read this question, he wants to disallow a sub-directory, but allow some urls that are in there.

Comment: Well, if he uses `Disallow: /dir/path_name.htm`, i think it will not block the folder (since it does not have trailing slash), but then again i never attempted this so i might be wrong